# Solr autocomplete implementation option: Suggester Component vs NGram

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to implement autocomplete there are two option
1. Suggester compnent
2. Using NGram analyzer

Kindly explain pros and cons of both

Answer (score 0):

Suggester is faster, especially for large collections since it uses dedicated data structures. NGrams is more flexible.

Both approaches have a lot of customization available, so specific trade-offs really depend on your business requirement.